# cordova build fails because it can't find build tools

Tags: cordova, build

Build tools it is specifically asking for are located at C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools  How do I tell cordova where to look?

I have set location value to ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_HOME, ANDROID_BUILD, and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT and nothing works

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your path to `C:\Users\id\AppData\Local\Android`

Comment: I must be slow but I now have the latest gradle 7.5.1 but the android requirements still shows there is no avdmanager and the android studio does not show an avdmanager on the tools menu as shown in the documentation.  I have reinstalled to no avail.  Please help

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, in the latest version of Android Studio you do not have to set anything in the environmental variables as it is done automatically. It's always better to keep your SDK folder in the root drive i.e. C\Android\SDK.

Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the Android Studio once? keep every thing to default and don't make any changes. Just download all the SDKs required and don't set any target sdk version in your project for a moment. This should work definitely.

Comment: set path per answer #1 no change

Comment: uninstalled and reinstalled android studio accepting all defaults and no change

Comment: PS D:\eclipse> cordova requirements

Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
Command failed with exit code 1: avdmanager list target
'avdmanager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Gradle: installed C:\Gradle\gradle-6.9.1\bin\gradle.BAT

Comment: Where can I find avdmanager?

Comment: Sir, the gradle version has to be recent ...mine is 7.4.2 ... you must install all the android studio updates. AVD manager can be found under Tools > Device Manager

Comment: there is no Device Manager directory under Tools in the sdk

Comment: I am talking about Android studio. Once you have opened Android Studio, you have to navigate through the menu on the top. Tools > Device Manager. You can also click on the AVD icon at the upper right hand corner. Just hover your mouse and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got it to work on windows 11,
Cordova 12.0.0,
Latest Gradle 8.1.1,
Latest version of Android Studio,

Add the following System environment variables.

> ANDROID_HOME=%localappdata%\Android\Sdk
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=%localappdata%\Android\Sdk

Edit the Path variable and make sure you have the following listed.

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin
> (this line item should be listed in top.)

> %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\emulator

> %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platform-tools

> %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\build-tools

> %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\platforms

> %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools

> %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\tools\bin

> C:\gradle\gradle-8.1.1\bin    (Gradle needs to be downloaded manually and extracted to a local folder)

> %ANDROID_SDK_ROOT%\cmdline-tools\latest\bin

Do not use the old depreciated android tools\bin.
Use Java 11 - do not use Java 8 (1.8)